# TableView _:didSelectRowAt: is triggered only on slide touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm showing a UITableView with default cells and isEditing/allowsMultipleSelection with `true` value.
On `_:viewForHeaderInSection:` I'm set a CustomView with a custom delegate to get feedback about changes on this view.

When the user tap on a cell, this cell turn to selected color, but when user release the cell, it changes to unselected, on this moment `_:didSelectRowAt:` was not triggered.

When the user tap on cell and make a slide (tap, hold, and move) gesture, the cell is turned selected and `_:didSelectRowAt:` is triggered.

I need the normal tableView behaviour (select on tap), with multiple selection.

I'm tried to remove all other delegates on this view (including custom view for header in section), remove completely the custom header view, remove UITableView from my .xib an add it again, change position when tableview is setup, set `isEditing` and `allowsMultipleSelection` properties to `false`.

#### Setup TableView

```swift
private func setupTableView() {
   self.tableView.delegate = self
   self.tableView.dataSource = self
   self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
   self.tableView.isEditing = true
   self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
   self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
}
```

### tableview delegate and datasource

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private let header = TableViewHeader()


    [...]


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datasource.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        self.header.delegate = self
        return self.header.view
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            if selectedRows.count > 5 {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

### I did remove a custom UITapGestureRecognizer from my view and now works fine!

Comment: `allowsMultipleSelection` and `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` set false.. not working ?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint in your `didSelectRowAt` table view delegate method, what is the type and value of `selectedRows`?

Comment: @NiravKotecha I need multiple selection on tableView, I tried to disable it, but still not working

Comment: did you applied tap gesture in that view controller ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha your are right, I was added a tap gesture to view to resignFirstResponder and it was blocking my tap gesture on tableview. I removed the gesture and now works fine!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check that you have applied tap gesture on that view controller or not because it will block you in tableView selection.

by following tap gesture delegate method code, you can unblock your tableView selection.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if([touch.view isDescendantOfView:YOUR_TABLE_NAME])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the problem, my view had a custom tap gesture and was blocking tableview tap gesture.